# Kegerator CO2 Line

Tags: co2, kegerator

New to the homebrewing boards and I was hoping someone could help me with a quick kegerator question.  I picked up a Danby DKC146SLDB from Costco over the weekend and I just got around to setting it up yesterday.  Most of the installation went well, but there is a bit of space around the hole where the CO2 line goes from the external tank into the refrigerated portion of the unit.

It seems like this could waste quite a bit of energy, as well as presenting issues with regulating the keg temperatures.  I was debating buying a bit of putty and insulating tape to put around this area, but I was curious if anyone else has encountered this issue.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there cold air leaking out of the fridge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The putty idea will work just fine. Tape will also work, but use something that won't dehydrate and become permeable such as "foil tape" or "tuck tape" (which actually has an R value of 2.5!). If using putty or tape, seal both sides of the hole (either side of the insulation). Spray foam will work great however it is very difficult to re-seal a can of "great stuff" so to use an entire can for a tiny hole would be a waste. Whenever I use that stuff I make a list of areas around the house to spray/ fill so I can be sure to use the entire can. That stuffs not cheap!

Answer (score 0):

I'd just shoot a bit of insulation foam, like "Great Stuff" into there and the tape it off so it looks pretty (the foam discolors after just a short time).

Is your hole near the top or the bottom of the unit? Since cool air sinks, you have less potential for an energy-consuming leak if the hole is nearer to the top. Top-lidded deep freeze units work on this principle--even when you open the lid, very little cool air is lost.